# How to show hidden icon and remove text when the button is clicked

Tags: html, css, reactjs

From the picture attached, the "check" icon is visible. If I do visibility: hidden; on the icon, how do I show the "check" icon and remove the word "Login" in the button when its clicked. I do not want the icon visible when the button is not clicked.

[image]

I have done something like this when the button is clicked, this is what I want for the output. But one last thing, how do I not show the "check" icon at first . I only want the text "Login" when it is not clicked

[image]

```
<button className = "submitBtn"><AiFillCheckCircle className = "check" size = {35}/><span>Login</span></button>
```

CSS

```
.submitBtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 400px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  color: black;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: white;
  justify-content: center;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.submitBtn span {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.submitBtn:focus {
  width: 50px;
  height: 40px;
  color: rgb(0, 255, 0);
}
```

Comment: You can add a state like const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(false) and onClick button change to true. Then you can use conditional isChecked to show one button or the other

Comment: But with that will I get the transition instead of blink to another button? For now my button width will decrease from 200px to 50px when its clicked, can see the width shorten animation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understood you correctly, you want to switch between icon and text. For that case, need to use `position: absolute;`, set to the center and hide it with `opacity: 0;`.
Second step, create extra class for switch and with toggle function.

```js
const AiFillCheckCircle = ({ name, size}) => {
  const style = {
    width: `${size}px`,
    height: `${size}px`
  };

  return ( <div className={name} style={style}>i </div>
  );
};

function App() {
  const [checked, setCheked] = React.useState(false);

  const toggle = () => setCheked(!checked);
  return ( 
    <button 
      className = {checked ? "submitBtn hide" : "submitBtn"} 
      onClick = {toggle}>
    
      <AiFillCheckCircle name = "check" size = {35}/> 
      <span>Login</span> 
    </button>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render( <App/>, rootElement);
```

```css
*,
::after,
::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
}

body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  background-color: hsl(201, 27%, 10%);
}


/* Solution css */

.submitBtn {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  color: black;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: white;
  justify-content: center;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.submitBtn span {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transform: scale(1.5);
}

.check {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.1);
  background: hsl(120, 100%, 50%);
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 2em;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}


/* switch */

.submitBtn.hide span {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0.1);
}

.submitBtn.hide .check {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```